# object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python

I am a beginner and i am facing problem in this class and in `__init__`:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_readings = 0

    def getname(self):
        longname = f'{self.year} {self.model} {self.year}'
        return longname.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        print(f'This car has {self.odometer_readings} miles on it')

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        if mileage >= self.odometer_readings:
            self.odometer_readings = mileage
        else:
            print('You cant roll back  the odometer')

    def increment_odometer(self, mileage):
        self.odometer_readings += miles

class Battery:
    def __init__(self, battery_size = 75):
        self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        print(f'This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery in it')

    def get_range(self):
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range = 260
        elif self.battery_size == 1000:
            range = 310
        print(f"This car can go {range} miles on a full charge")

class electriccar:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Teerth Jain/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/mycar.py", line 2, in <module>
    mycar = electriccar('tesla', 'ashduf', 297)
  File "C:/Users/Teerth Jain/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32\car.py", line 46, in __init__
    super().__init__(make, model, year)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Comment: you are calling `super` but the class `electriccar` is not inheriting from any class so it inherits from the default `object` which takes no arguments (you are passing to it 3)...

Comment: I'll assume you simply forgot to inherit from `Car` and will close this as a typo…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the base class of electriccar:

```py
class electriccar(Car):
    ....
```